# How to access local.setting.json db connection string with python

Tags: python-3.x, azure-functions

I have this local.settings.json in my local Azure function (Http triggered)

```
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "",
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "python"
  },
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "SQLConnectionString": "valid connection string "
  }
}
```

I want to access variable "SQLConnectionString" and use in my Python3.6 code.
I have found many guides for accessing this variable with C#, but I wasn't lucky to find how to do it via python.

Comment: Do you mind set the properties(such as username, password, port....) separately in the connect operation instead of connection string ?

Comment: Connection string will be hidden in Azure key Vault and accessed via azure env variables in future. But for testing purposes and developement I would like to have connection string in local.settings.json.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I test it just now and met the same error. You should modify your local.setting.json as below:

```
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "",
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "python",
    "SQLConnectionString": "cnx = mysql.connector.connect(user=\"test@hurytestmysqlserver\", password=\"Password123\", host=\"testmysqlserver.mysql.database.azure.com\", port=3306, database=\"xxx\", .....)"
  }
}
```

but not

```
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "",
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "python"
  },
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "SQLConnectionString": "xxxxxxxx"
  }
}
```

Please have a try.

Just as a supplement~(I wanted to provide the solution "os.environ[xxx]" but saw the solution provided by HariHaran, haha~)

Comment: yup modifying the local.setting.json without having nested "ConnectionStrings": {
    "SQLConnectionString": "xxxxxxxx"
  } helped. 

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Warning: in your sentence I think you missed the "s" in the word "settingS" to have really a filename named as  "local.settings.json" instead of "local.setting.json". In my case once well named and with your right syntax all is running well.

Answer (score 7):

You can access these settings by declaring import os and then using

`setting = os.environ["setting-name"]`.

More information - [Developer Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-python#environment-variables)

Comment: Tried:
import os
....
print(os.environ["SQLConnectionString"])
or
print(os.environ["ConnectionStrings"])

With the same result: System.Private.CoreLib: Exception while executing function: Functions.HttpTrigger. System.Private.CoreLib: Result: Failure
Exception: KeyError: 'SQLConnectionString'

Answer (score 6):

In Python you need to do following:

```py
import os
conn = os.environ["ConnectionStrings:SQLConnectionString"]
```

Comment: This is the best answer

Answer (score 2):

Hi you can also try this:

local.settings.json:

```
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
  "AzureWebJobsStorage": "",
  "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "python",
  "SQLConnectionString": "cnx = mysql.connector.connect(user=\"test@hurytestmysqlserver\", password=\"Password123\", host=\"testmysqlserver.mysql.database.azure.com\", port=3306, database=\"xxx\", .....)"
  }
}
```

python:

```
import os
SQLConnectionString = os.getenv("SQLConnectionString")
```

Remember to configure the azure function environment aswell otherwise the function will fail on deployment.