# Setting Connection String as App Setting/Environment Variable in Azure Function

Tags: python, azure, environment-variables, azure-functions, appsettings

In my Azure Function, I have specified an Environment Variable/App Setting for a database connection string. I can use the Environment Variable when I run the Function locally on my Azure Data Science Virtual Machine using VS Code and Python.

However, when I deploy the Function to Azure, I get an error: KeyValue is None, meaning that it cannot find the Environment Variable for the connection string. See error:

```
Exception while executing function: Functions.matchmodel Result: Failure
Exception: KeyError: 'CONNECTIONSTRINGS:PDMPDBCONNECTIONSTRING'
Stack:   File "/azure-functions 
  host/workers/python/3.7/LINUX/X64/azure_functions_worker/dispatcher.py", line 315, in 
  _handle__invocation_request self.__run_sync_func, invocation_id, fi.func, args)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/concurrent/futures/thread.py", line 57, in run
  result = self.fn(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
File "/azure-functions-host/workers/python/3.7/LINUX/X64/azure_functions_worker/dispatcher.py", 
  line 434, in __run_sync_func
  return func(**params)
File "/home/site/wwwroot/matchmodel/__init__.py", line 116, in main
File "/home/site/wwwroot/matchmodel/production/dataload.py", line 28, in query_dev_database
  setting = os.environ["CONNECTIONSTRINGS:PDMPDBCONNECTIONSTRING"]
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/os.py", line 679, in __getitem__
  raise KeyError(key) from None'
```

I have tried the following solutions:

- Added "CONNECTIONSTRINGS" to specify the Environment Variable in the Python script (which made it work locally)
  `setting = os.environ["CONNECTIONSTRINGS:PDMPDBCONNECTIONSTRING"]`
- Used `logging.info(os.environ)` to output my Environment Variables in the console. My connection string is listed.
- Added the connection string as Application Setting in the Azure Function portal.

[image]

- Added the Connection String as Connection Strings in the Azure Function portal.

[image]

Does anyone have any other solutions that I can try?

Comment: You could try removing `CONNECTIONSTRINGS:` from the name of the environment variable. `:` can cause issues, I believe mainly on Linux app service plans. Take care to remove it both in your code and in the application settings of the AppService.

Comment: I had to add ```CONNECTIONSTRINGS:``` in order to get it to run locally. It would not run locally until I added the key name.

Comment: Any update now?

Comment: I was able to edit the local.settings.json to remove the ```CONNECTIONSTRINGS:```. I had nested JSON and removed that. Now it runs locally with just ```"PDMPDBCONNECTIONSTRING"```. Trying to get it to run on Azure as Function still.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Actually you are almost get the right the connection string, however you use the wrong prepended string. Further more detailed information you could refer to this doc:[Configure connection strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-common#configure-connection-strings).

Which string to use it depends on which type you choose, like in my test I use a custom type. Then I should use `os.environ['CUSTOMCONNSTR_testconnectionstring']` to get the value.

From the doc you could find there are following types:

- SQL Server: SQLCONNSTR_
- MySQL: MYSQLCONNSTR_
- SQL Database: SQLAZURECONNSTR_
- Custom: CUSTOMCONNSTR_

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I have tried it with and without the prefix. When i deploy it without the prefix, the prefix is automatically added. I can see the prefix there when I ```print(os.environ)``` to the console, which I can view in the Azure Portal App Insights using ```func.HttpResponse(print(os.environ))```. I can see the correct Environment Variables but the connection still isn't working.

Comment: So you got a new problem: could not connect the database with the connection string? Cause it's different problem, suppose you should create a new question. And if this could help you, you could accept it as the answer.

Comment: I don't think you have to specify the type of connection string. That gets picked up automatically based on your settings in the portal.

Comment: I made a new post about a slightly different issue. Please respond if you can! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60893887/azure-function-database-connection

Comment: So you have solved your problem with my way, if this could help you you could accept it as the answer.

Answer (score 2):

I was struggling with this and found out this solution:

```
import os

setting = os.getenv("mysetting")
```

Answer (score 1):

In Functions application settings, such as service connection strings, are exposed as environment variables during execution. You can access these settings by declaring `import os` and then using

`setting = os.environ["mysetting"]`

As Alex said, try to remove `CONNECTIONSTRINGS:` from the name of the environment variable. In azure portal just add `mysetting` in application settings as keyName.

[image]

Comment: I had to add ```CONNECTIONSTRINGS:``` in order to get it to run locally. It would not run locally until I added the key name. I have tried to deploy to Azure Function with and without ```CONNECTIONSTRINGS:```; neither options will work.

Comment: How do your store your connection? You could just store it under `values` like this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58535162/how-to-access-local-setting-json-db-connection-string-with-python?answertab=active#tab-top).

Comment: Yes, I store the connection string as a value and give the setting a name like you did with mysetting. Still does not work.

Comment: I made a new post about a slightly different issue. Please respond if you can! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60893887/azure-function-database-connection

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the issue with help from George and selected George's answer as the correct answer.

I changed the code to `os.environ["SQLCONNSTR_PDMPDBCONNECTIONSTRING"]` but also I had been deploying the package from VS Code to Azure via the following code using Azure Command Line Interface (Azure CLI). This code overwrites Azure App Settings with the local.settings.json.

`func azure functionapp publish <MY_FUNCTION_NAME> --publish-local-settings -i --overwrite-settings -y`

I think that was causing changes to the type of database that I had specified in Azure App Settings (SQL Server), so when I had previously tried `os.environ["SQLCONNSTR_PDMPDBCONNECTIONSTRING"]` it didn't work because I was overwriting my Azure settings using my local.settings.json, which did not specify a database type.

I finally got it to work by deploying using the VS Code Extension called Azure Functions (Azure Functions: Deploy to Function App). This retains the settings that I had created in Azure App Services.